# Angular 2: Is usage of Parentheses / Square brackets mandatory?

Tags: angular

In the Angular 2 previews released so far, the syntax of the markup has been modified from `ng-` prefixes to square parentheses and square brackets.

Whereas before one would have:

```html
<input ng-model="userName" />
<button ng-click="btnClick()">Run</button>
```

The new syntax is:

```html
<input [value]="userName" />
<button (click)="btnClick()">Run</button>
```

Does anybody know if this syntax is/will be mandatory, and without alternatives?

We currently have an application in which the HTML is generated through XSLT, and `[` and `(` are not valid attributes - thereby being unable to generate Angular 2 JS syntax.

Comment: You do know that Angular 2.0 won't be released for at least a year and it's currently in active development. I think you are jumping the gun to be asking this question now.

Comment: I agree, this is too early to ask about that. I will keep on adding more resources to my answer as I research the Internet on the topic.

Comment: I heard them stated after ng-conf that this is not final. It is just a demonstration of idea and might change by final release. Because a lot of people were confused with this.

Comment: yes, but on the long run, directives are staying. so, even if it is not supported officially. someone can create a module that supports 1.3, though it sounds easier than it is

Comment: It's out.  It didn't change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not mandatory - see [here](http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/all-about-angular-2-0/).

Please checkout the directives section (near the middle of the page):
the "Decorator Directive" is still there, which means with regards to your question.

There will be a fall back way for sure.

Do checkout [the official demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNmWybAyBHI) as well: `ng-model`/`click` are used in that as well.

Answer (score 53):

In fact, `[]` and `()` *are* valid HTML chars in attributes. If you generate HTML code on the server-side or use any other pre-processor that can't handle those characters, you can always use the equivalent canonical syntax.

- `[]` is a shorthand for `bind-*`, hence `[propertyName] == bind-property-name`
- `()` is a shorthand for `on-*`, hence `(eventName) == on-event-name`

This syntax is used mainly because of two reasons (**and actually mandatory**):

- **Escaping** - Element attributes need to be escaped. If you have an image tag with a dynamic `src` like this: `<img src="{{imageSource}}">` this would result in a `404` error, because the browser immediately tries to request the given URL. The URL in that particular moment is `{{imageSource}}` which is for sure no valid URL. Therefore we have the `ngSrc` attribute in Angular 1. We can use it like `<img ng-src="{{imageSource}}">`. What it does is, it waits until the interpolation is evaluated **and then** adds a `src` attribute the image. This ensures that no wrong request is made due to asynchronous interpolation evaluation. There are a couple of more directives that help out on this, like `ng-href`. Now, when it comes to Web Components, attribute names are not deterministic anymore. Web Components can define their own attributes which the framework doesn't know about. So we have two options: we either create a directive for each attribute that needs escaping (oh noes!), or we come up with a more generic syntax that Angular understands and lets the framework intercept accordingly. This is why `[propertyName]` has been introduced. Again, this is just a shortcut. Use the canonical syntax if that doesn't suite you.
- **Property Binding** - Now you might wonder why `[propertyName]` and not `[attributeName]`. It turns out that we come across a another problem when dealing with custom elements, that are not aware of Angular's directive lifecycle. In Angular, we could decide how a value is bound to an element's scope. So in this code: `<my-directive foo="bar">`, `bar` could be either just string, or an object that is two-way data bound. We only know that by looking into the directive's implementation. However, Web Components and Custom Elements simply don't know about Angular's lifecycle. Which means, an attribute value always a string, because that's what an attribute is in HTML. In order to make sure that we can still pass other values than just strings to any element, **Angular 2 binds to element properties instead of attributes**. Because a property on a DOM element's object can be anything, not just a string. So with `[]` syntax, we also tell Angular that we do want to bind to the element's property, not it's attribute. This also means that now the consumer of a directive/element/webcomponent is in charge of deciding how a value is passed to it.

I've written an [article](http://pascalprecht.github.io/2014/10/25/integrating-web-components-with-angularjs/) about it that covers that topic, also there's a talk from [ngeurope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSTNTXtQwaY).

I hope this clears things up!

Comment: While they may be valid HTML characters, they are not valid XML characters. As said in the question, the output HTML is being generated as a result of an XSLT and, even in output/@mode HTML, requires that the content of the XSLT be valid XML.

Having said that, I thank you for the comment because it does indeed state what the alternative to the new bracket/parenthesis syntax is -- and that this alternative is entirely compatible with the aforementioned rendering pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try an example that will clear your thoughts.

Consider the code:

```
get test() {
    return true;
}
```

If you use the following code, the *"[visible]*" attribute receives *"test"* as a value.

```
<input type="button" [visible]="test" />
```

But if you use:

```
<input type="button" (visible)="test" />
```

It receives the value of *"test"* method.

In other words [] binds the property and () binds the event.
Please, some one correct me if I'm doing wrong.

More details [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) and [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-one-and-two-way-data-bindings-with-examples/)

I hope it helps.